# Problem with org.springdoc swagger openapi 2 and springboot 3 when extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport for custom WebConfig

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to configure the org.sprindoc-openapi library in Spring Boot 3. In my application, I need to extend the WebMvcConfigurationSupport class for some custom configurations that I need to apply to my REST API, and here comes the problem. If I extend the WebMvcConfigurationSupport class, I can access /v3/api-docs, but I can no longer access /swagger-ui.html to browse the APIs. If I remove the extension of the WebMvcConfigurationSupport class, everything works correctly, but I need my configuration, so I can't remove it.

Checking in the Actuator, the /swagger-ui.html path is mapped, but if I try to access it, I receive a 404 page not found error. I'm sharing my configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected RequestMappingHandlerMapping createRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new VersionedHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }

}
```

and this is the org.springdoc config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.springdoc" })
public class OpenApiConfig {
    @Bean
    OpenAPI coreMicroserviceOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("xxxx")
                        .description("desc")
                        .version("1.0"));
    }
}
```

below the dependencies used:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thank you all in advance. I hope that someone among you has found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works for me but you have to use the 2.X version of the [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/v2/) supporting OpenAPI 3.0 with Spring Boot 3:

**Spring Boot dependencies:**

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Open API dependency:**

Don't get fooled. The 2.X baseline and the whole [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/v2/) library support the Open API 3.0 specification.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Spring Boot application**

Make sure the **@RestController** beans are properly component-scanned.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.company")
public class Application {

}
```

**Web configuration class**

Use `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` instead of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   // code
}
```

---

Once you include this configuration, reimport the Maven project, build and run the application, you can access the Swagger UI here: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated in spring 3.xxx. By the spring doc, It should be used the WebMvcConfiguer instead that in my case I think is not good..

Comment: I found a solution by extending instead the WebMvcRegistrations...I will post my solution.

Comment: I haven't heard of that. I am waiting for your post :)